# Over any field, if some polynomials are algebraically dependent, are their derivatives linearly dependent?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, jacobian, positive-characteristic, algebraic-independence

Denote by $P_n$ the space of all polynomials in $n$ variables, with coefficients in a field $\mathbb F$.

A collection of polynomials $(f_1,\cdots,f_m)=\vec f\in P_n\!^m$ is called *algebraically dependent* if there is some polynomial $g\neq0$ in $P_m$ such that $g\circ\vec f=0$ in $P_n$.

According to the Jacobian criterion, $(f_1,\cdots,f_m)$ is algebraically dependent if and only if $(\vec\nabla f_1,\cdots,\vec\nabla f_m)$ is linearly dependent over $P_n$. But this equivalence generally requires $\mathbb F$ to have characteristic $0$.

With characteristic $p\neq0$, is the "only if" part still true?

---

See [this thesis by Sinhababu](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/nitin/theses/sinhababu-2014.pdf) (section 2.5), also [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/373823/134099).

Seeking a contradiction, suppose $(f_1,\cdots,f_m)$ is algebraically dependent but $(\vec\nabla f_1,\cdots,\vec\nabla f_m)$ is linearly independent. Let $g\neq0$ be a polynomial of minimal degree such that $g\circ\vec f=0$. Differentiating by the chain rule,

$$0=\vec\nabla(g\circ\vec f)=\sum_{k=1}^m\Big((\partial_k g)\circ\vec f\Big)\vec\nabla f_k,$$

so, by linear independence, each coefficient must vanish:

$$0=(\partial_k g)\circ\vec f.$$

If any $\partial_k g\in P_m$ is non-zero, since its degree is lower than that of $g$, this would contradict minimality of $g$. Hence

$$0=\partial_k g$$

for each $k$; that is, $\vec\nabla g=0$.

If  $\mathbb F$ has characteristic $0$, this implies that $g=c\in\mathbb F$ is constant; but then $0\neq g=c=g\circ\vec f=0$.

Now suppose $\mathbb F$ has characteristic $p\neq0$. Vanishing derivative $\vec\nabla g=0$ is equivalent to $g=h\circ(x_1^p,\cdots,x_m^p)$ for some polynomial $h\in P_m$, where $x_1,\cdots,x_m$ are the variables. *(I was trying to use notation which doesn't explicitly refer to these variables....)*

If, further, $\mathbb F$ is perfect, meaning that the Frobenius function $\varphi:x\mapsto x^p$ for $x\in\mathbb F$ is bijective, then $h\circ(x_1^p,\cdots,x_m^p)$ can be written as $(\varphi^{-1}h)^p$, where $\varphi^{-1}$ applies only to the coefficients of $h$, but the $p$th power applies to the whole polynomial. Thus

$$0=g\circ\vec f=(\varphi^{-1}h)^p\circ\vec f=\Big((\varphi^{-1}h)\circ\vec f\Big)^p.$$

But then $(\varphi^{-1}h)\circ\vec f=0$ contradicts minimality of $g$, as the degree of $\varphi^{-1}h$ is the same as the degree of $h$ which is $\tfrac1p$ of the degree of $g$ (and $g$ is not constant).

---

How can we proceed when $\mathbb F$ is not perfect (for example, an infinite field of rational expressions over a finite field)?

Or is the statement not true? At least it is true for $m=1$: if a single polynomial $f$ is algebraically dependent, then it's constant (else $g\circ f$ would have positive degree), so its derivative is $\vec\nabla f=0$, which is linearly dependent.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure this works, but: the $F_i$ are algebraically independent over the field $F$ iff $(F_{\cdot}^{\alpha})_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^m}$ is $F$-linearly independent. But by rank invariance, this happens iff this family is $\overline{F}$-independent, ie iff $(F_1,\ldots,F_m)$ is algebraically independent over $\overline{F}$. Same for the second condition, so you can assume that your field is algebraically closed, and you have solved the problem in this case.

Comment: The linked MO question now has an answer to this. I don't think we can close this as a duplicate....